# android "which application you want to use" dialog when redirecting to an activity

Tags: android

these are the 2 intent filters of my 2 activities:

StartActivity

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

HomeActivity

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I'm in the home activity and when I call:

```
  activity.startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));
```

Android shows a dialog that askes which application I'd like to use to go on.
Someone is so kind to explain me why??

EDIT

I'm gonna be clearer:
 StartActivity -> Contains login e and signin actions
 HomeActivity -> Contains the most part of the app

My scenario:
 I successfully logged in and now I'm in the HomeActivity, but when I log out and redirect to start activity android shows a dialog "With wich application do you wanna complete this action?" (or something like this) instead of redirecting me to the StartActivity

Comment: `I'm in the home activity and when i call` do you mean your home activity and if so why you need a home activity, or du you mean the home screen which is more likely a widget

Comment: Don't you want to give an update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need a  `Action HOME` but it looks like your problem is the `Category DEFAULT`. Due to the android docs this category is defined as :

`Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the user any activities without it set when performing an action on some data. Note that this is normally -not- set in the Intent when initiating an action -- it is for use in intent filters specified in packages.
Constant Value: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"`

So I think changing this one to the right one which fits your need will solve the problem. Just a suggestion!

Read more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's resolved, but I avoided the problem using

```
 activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,StartActivity.class));
```